# How can I get odd numbers from listbox1, and sum them?

Tags: c#

I have to get even numbers from listbox, and then to sum all numbers, but it's not working, and I'm not sure how to fix it.
Here's my code

```
        private void radioButton1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int zbir = 0;
            int brojBrojeva = 0;
            if(radioButton1.Checked)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
                {
                    **if (listBox1.Items[i]%2==0)**//Mistake is here
                    {
                        zbir += Convert.ToInt32(listBox1.Items[i]);
                        brojBrojeva++;
                    }
                }
                txtZbir.Text="" + zbir;
                txtBroj.Text = "" + brojBrojeva;
            }
        }
```

Comment: _"if (listBox1.Items[i]%2==0)//Mistake is here"_ -- huh. You know the mistake is there but still can't fix it? Anyway...your expression finds the even numbers, not the odd ones. Even numbers are the ones that have a remainder of zero when divided by two. Odd numbers have a remainder of one. If you change your code to `if (listBox1.Items[i]%2!=0)` then you'll be using the odd numbers instead of the even numbers, which according to your _title_ is what you want. ...

Comment: ... Of course, your title conflicts with the claim that you _"have to get even numbers from listbox"_. So, you should probably figure out what you actually want. And then just write the code to do that instead of the other thing.

Comment: @PeterDuniho it is unlikely OP get as far as dividing by 2 - the [Items](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listbox.objectcollection.item?view=net-5.0) return object and it should fail to compile... Now it is very hard to know what exact problem OP has... (in addition to not knowing what they want as you pointed out - really can't be odd and even at the same time :) )

Comment: I knew that mistake is there because Visual Studio tells me that operator % cannot be applied to operands of type 'object' and 'int', but I do not know how to solve it

Comment: You should edit your question to include the error you were getting so people stop down voting it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't say, but I'm assuming that the reason it isn't working is because you're getting a compiler error? Something like [`CS0019`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs0019)?

`ListBox.Items` returns an instance of `ListBox.ObjectCollection`. You can see that the [indexer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listbox.objectcollection.item) returns an instance of `object` and not an instance of `int`. You need to convert the item in the `ListBox` back to an `int` before you can use the `%` operator.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    int listBoxObj = Convert.ToInt32(listBox1.Items[i]);
    if (listBoxObj % 2 == 0)
    {
        zbir += listBoxObj;
        brojBrojeva++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Before applying the modulus operator, you must first convert your listbox item to integer because C# is a strongly typed language and the listbox holds a collection of `objects`. Refer to the documentation on [boxing and unboxing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/boxing-and-unboxing) for more background.
2. You can check if a number is odd or even using the binary `&` operator. EG, `if ((n&1)==0) // then even` This uses a single cpu instruction instead of the 15 instructions required for a division operation.

```cs
private void radioButton1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int zbir = 0;
    int brojBrojeva = 0;
    if(radioButton1.Checked)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            int val = Convert.ToInt32(listBox1.Items[i])
            if((val&1) == 0)
            {
                zbir += val;
                brojBrojeva++;
            }
        }
        txtZbir.Text="" + zbir;
        txtBroj.Text = "" + brojBrojeva;
    }
}
```